# Intercept HTTP Connect Requests with OkHTTP

Tags: okhttp

I want to add a custom header to HTTP Connect requests as a means for customized communication with a proxy.

Is there a way to do this? Ideally I would do it through a Network Interceptor that sees the HTTP Connect requests.  But this doesn't seem to be the case by default when testing with a sample application.

Thanks,
Y.